# Storing the order of entities

Tags: datomic

If I have entities with the attribute `:fruit`:

```
apple
banana
grapes
tomato
```

and a feature allowing a user to order his fruits:

```
1 grapes
2 apple
3 tomato
4 banana
```

Is there a good way to store fruit order to the database with the expectation that a fruit may be deleted, a fruited added, and fruits reordered?

A naive solution is to add an order column. A problem with that is expensive updates. Say I have an entity: `1000000 durian`. I suddenly decide it's my favorite fruit and move it to the top. This causes 999999 fruits to require an order update.

Comment: Here's a blog post that gives code on doing exactly this expensive update: http://augustl.com/blog/2013/ordering_cardinality_many_in_datomic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built-in way to accomplish your goal in any database, whether PostgreSQL, Datomic, or anything.  However, there is an easy answer.

Just convert your proposed "priority" column from an integer to a floating-point value.  Then you can always insert a new entry between any two existing items without the need to change anything.  Suppose you start with

```
1.0 grape
2.0 apple
3.0 tomato
4.0 banana
```

and you then decide that to add a `pear` between `grape` and `apple`.  Just insert is as:

```
1.0 grape
1.5 pear
2.0 apple
3.0 tomato
4.0 banana
```

You then decide to insert `cherry` between `grape` and `pear`, so you get:

```
1.0  grape
1.25 cherry
1.5  pear
2.0  apple
3.0  tomato
4.0  banana
```

Then, whenever you want to examine your list you simply fetch both the priority column and the name column, sort by priority, and you are done.

Comment: With the priority solution: just be aware that, as the list evolves, progressive halving, like progressive doubling, will quickly exhaust the precision of even a 64-bit float. I would have serious reservations using this for anything long-lived.

Comment: If you wanted to be really pathological, you could always use BigDecimal values like `1.5M`.

Comment: True, but 'pathological' might be an excellent way to describe the results of very big BigDecimals ;)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, Datomic doesn't have this built in, and to be fair neither does many other databases.

You have the "order" column approach that you mentioned, which also has the problem you mentioned. Gaps isn't the worst part really, since you can still get correct sorting with some gaps, it becomes even worse if you want to insert an item in the middle, then you *have* to update the following entities. And you should probably do it all in a transaction function unless you're certain your peer is single threaded.

There's also the linked list approach, where each entity points to the next and the last doesn't point to anything. Appending, prepending and slicing in the middle becomes constant operations.